# Run Mechanize-based Perl Script on server-side

Tags: javascript, perl, mechanize, server-side

I am new to web developing and till now, I only used client-side programming (Javascript) on my website. My website is used to generate possible class schedules for my university given an input and comparing it with a data structure that has all the classes.

I update this data structure manually by running a Perl Script and encoding the result in JSON and then edit the .html. However, I would like to allow the server to run this script and automatically update itself every time interval.

Please keep in mind that I am a newbie in server-side.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is a linux or other unix machine, what you're describing is a cron job.

man cron

should get you started. I'm sure there is something similar on windows servers, but I have no idea what it would be.